# Spring logging to file (log4j)

Tags: spring, logging, log4j

I have a Maven project where I want to enable Spring logging to a log file. The logging system I use is log4j. I have put this in my log4j.properties file, but it's not enough:

```
log4j.category.org.springframework=ALL
```

I would like to either get the log to an existing appender, or to a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a separate file Define the root logger with appender file like this :

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = info, FILE  

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/your/path/to/logfile/logfilename.log

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=info

# Set the append to false, should not overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true

# Set the DatePattern
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=[%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L] Method:- %M : %m%n
```

**Edit**

set log level with this in properties file according to [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging)

```
 log4j.level.org.springframework.web: info
```

Comment: But how will it pick up that it should log Spring? I have several appenders in the log4j properties file already, but when i added the line for spring, it didn't come up in the log.